# MySQL server feature gap on Windows and Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, windows

Is there any gap or difference in **features** of **MySQL Server** on Windows and Linux? Feature refers to below aspects:

- common DBMS functionalities such as Stored Procedures, Updateable Views, Distributed Transactions
- differences in behavior caused by system features.
- differences in configuration that have a impact on performance such as Shared Memory on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

No, in terms of features there is no difference between Windows and Linux versions of mysql. There are certain configuration options that may make sense on one of them only, for example see [identifier case sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html), that you have to consider when migrating databases between the 2 platforms. Mysql documentation has a section on [limits on Windows platform](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limits-windows.html) that lists those differences that may cause real headaches.

Obviously, there may be performance differences and tuning differences, but those have nothing to do with features.

Comment: Hi, I found some configurations on windows like connect to mysql server with pipe or shared memory, but I'm not sure are them a feature or not, how do you think of them?

Comment: I don't think that is a feature. You can connect to mysql on both platforms, just you have slightly different options, that's all. This is definitely not the same league as the features you described in the OP. Any differences in those would mean that you would essentially have to treat the 2 platforms as different rdbms.

Comment: One performance difference is that Windows seems to be terribly slow in opening/closing files.

Comment: The "mysql server" -- do you mean `mysqld` or `mysql`?  mysqld should not use shared memory.  Piping mysql to/from another process -- Windows (not mysql) is a bit lame in this area.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is whether to treat the 2 platforms as "2 different rdbms", the answer is a resounding "no".

The core product performs identically on both platforms with virtually no differences.  Some add-on tools don't work on Windows, because of limitations of Windows.

- Case folding in database and table names -- easy to work around.
- File path use `/` versus `\` -- whoopie.
- Symlinks -- does anyone care?
- Use of Galera, mysql sandbox, LVM snapshots, etc.  These are tools for production environments; the big players do not even consider Windows when buying production servers.

I answer lots of forum questions.  In the back of my mind, I think about whether the answer depends on version, SSD drives, OS, memory size, etc.  Almost never is OS a factor in the answers.

Even the bytes on MySQL's files are identical.